# 0 temperature & hummidity DH11

Tags: arduino-uno

Alright so I'm having problems with my code. Its my first time using DH11

I keep on getting that temperature is 0 degrees so as the humidity

```
#include "dht.h"
#define dht_apin A0

dht DHT;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("DHT11 Humidity & temperature Sensor\n\n");
  delay(1000);

}

void loop()
{

    DHT.read11(dht_apin);

    Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("%  ");
    Serial.print("temperature = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature); 
    Serial.println("C  ");

    delay(5000)


}
```

What Im getting is basically

> Current humidity = 0.00%  temperature = 0.00C

Comment: did you run the example code?

Comment: Suggestion: drop the `dht11` in favor of Bosch's `BME280` (not BMP!).  It measures temperature, humidity AND pressure.

Comment: @tonygil ... and it doesn't make use of dump 1-wire protocoll. As long as 1w is not supported by hardware this turns out to be a game-breaker in many professional (non-makers) applications (my experience). BME is a great alternative and provides SPI and i2c

Comment: Do you have the external pullup?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into problems when using some `DHT` library versions.  May I suggest that you try using a different version of `dht.h`?

This version works for me (there is a [newer version](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DHTLib) I have NOT tested):

dht.h (606B 6/12/2012)

```
// 
//    FILE: dht.h
// VERSION: 0.1.00
// PURPOSE: DHT Temperature & Humidity Sensor library for Arduino
//
//     URL: http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DHTLib
//
// HISTORY:
// see dht.cpp file
// 

#ifndef dht_h
#define dht_h

#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#define DHT_LIB_VERSION "0.1.00"

class dht
{
public:
    int read11(uint8_t pin);
    int read22(uint8_t pin);
    double humidity;
    double temperature;

private:
    uint8_t bits[5];  // buffer to receive data
    int read(uint8_t pin);
};
#endif
//
// END OF FILE
//
```